# How to Check if a value is within a range of numbers using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a simple calculator which calculates the discount percentage when entering the price in the field, I have two different discount types.

1. If the price is in `10-90` range you get a 50%-discount.
2. If the price is in `100-900` range you get a 90%-discount.

Problem:
When I am entering `100` in the input field both type is selected, my aim is to select only second type of discount.

[Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-goldwasser-wp168?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Always include all relevant code in the question itself; external code representations should always only be an add-on.

Comment: You check if total > max. Remove this to get to result you want :) Fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-curran-fmqx9?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that setActiveRange function is working as you have written it - basically, it will return true every time the 'total > price' condition is fulfilled. Remove that part and it is gonna work. Code sample:

```
 methods: {
    setActiveRange(min, max) {
      let total = this.price;
      if (total && total >= min && total <= max) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass discount to your method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      price: "",
      cascadeSugg: [
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "10-90USD take 50% discount",
          min: 10,
          max: 90,
          discount: 50,
          created_at: "2021-10-28T03:04:33.000000Z",
          updated_at: "2021-10-28T03:41:49.000000Z",
          start_date: "2021-10-28",
          end_date: "2021-10-31",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "100-900USD take 90% discount",
          min: 100,
          max: 200,
          discount: 90,
          created_at: "2021-10-28T03:54:28.000000Z",
          updated_at: "2021-10-28T03:54:28.000000Z",
          start_date: "2021-10-28",
          end_date: "2021-10-31",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    setActiveRange(min, max, disc) {
      let total = this.price;
      if(total && total <= 99 && total >= min) {
        return true
      } else if ((total && total >= 100 && disc > 50)) {
        return true;
      }
    },
  },
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.active {
  color: #F48245;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <div class="cascade-discount">
      <input type="text" v-model="price" />
      <div
        class="cascade-item"
        v-for="cascade in cascadeSugg"
        :key="cascade.id"
      >
        <p
          class="m-0"
          :class="{ active: setActiveRange(cascade.min, cascade.max, cascade.discount) }"
        >
          {{ cascade.title }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that I am getting `cascadeSugg` data with API call, and it's fully dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple if-else statement to check the range of the values

```
if(price => 10 && price <= 90){
//get 50% Discount
}else if(price => 100 && price <= 900){
//get 90%Discount
}
```